# Suplementary law and reciprocity

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

Let $p$ odd prime. If $\omega\in\overline{\mathbb{F_p}}$ is a 8-th primitive root of unity.

Then if $\gamma=\omega+\omega^{-1}$.

Why is

i) $\gamma^p=\omega^ p+\omega^{-p}=\omega+\omega^{-1}=\gamma$  if $p\equiv\pm1 \ (mod \ 8)$

ii) $\gamma^p=\omega^ p+\omega^{-p}=\omega^3+\omega^{-3}=-(\omega+\omega^{-1})=\gamma$  if $p\equiv\pm3 \ (mod \ 8)$?

Thus

$\gamma^p=(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}\gamma$ therefore $\gamma^p=\gamma$ if and only if $(-1)^{(p^2-1/8)}=1$ if and only if $\left( \displaystyle\frac{2}{p} \right)=(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}$.

Thanks you all.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? There are several ideas coming together in this proof.

Comment: i), ii), and $\gamma^p=(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}\gamma$; thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i) If $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8$, then $\omega^p + \omega^{-p}$ is either $\omega^1 + \omega^{-1}$ or $\omega^{-1} + \omega^1$, which are both equal.

ii) If $p \equiv \pm 3 \pmod 8$, then $\omega^p + \omega^{-p}$ is either $\omega^3 + \omega^{-3}$ or $\omega^{-3} + \omega^3$, which are both equal. Factoring out an $\omega^4 = \omega^{-4} = -1$ gives us $-(\omega + \omega^{-1}) = -\gamma$.

The $(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}$ is just a way of picking out the right sign. Honestly, if you know that $2$ is a QR mod $p$ iff $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8$, you can just use that result directly, without passing through the $(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}$ step.

Comment: Sorry Henry; but why $\omega^p + \omega^{-p}$ is either $\omega^1 + \omega^{-1}$ or $\omega^{-1} + \omega^1$? Thanks.

Comment: Well, if $p = 8k + r$, $\omega^p = \omega^8k \omega^r = \omega^r$, so for part i), we only need to check two cases: plus and minus one.

Comment: In the part: Honestly, if you know that 2 is a QR mod p iff $p\equiv\pm 1$; is the Euler's criterion? 

$\left( \displaystyle\frac{2}{p} \right)=2^{(p-1)/2} \ (mod \ p)$

Comment: It's not Euler's Criterion; there's a separate theorem that $2^{(p-1)/2} \equiv (-1)^{(p^2 - 1)/8} \pmod 8$, but I can't remember the name offhand.